# Appending a dictionary to a list in a loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I am trying to take a dictionary and append it to a list. The dictionary then changes values and then is appended again in a loop. It seems that every time I do this, all the dictionaries in  the list change their values to match the one that was just appended.

For example:

```
>>> dict = {}
>>> list = []
>>> for x in range(0,100):
...     dict[1] = x
...     list.append(dict)
... 
>>> print list
```

I would assume the result would be `[{1:1}, {1:2}, {1:3}... {1:98}, {1:99}]` but instead I got:

```
[{1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}, {1: 99}]
```

Comment: You are filling `list` (which you shouldn't name `list`) with references to the same `dict` (which you shouldn't call `dict`)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You need to append a *copy*, otherwise you are just adding references to the same dictionary over and over again:

```
yourlist.append(yourdict.copy())
```

I used `yourdict` and `yourlist` instead of `dict` and `list`; you don't want to mask the built-in types.

Answer (score 15):

When you create the `adict` dictionary outside of the loop, you are appending the same dict to your `alist` list. It means that all the copies point to the same dictionary and you are getting the last value `{1:99}` every time. Just create every dictionary inside the loop and now you have your 100 different dictionaries.

```
alist = []
for x in range(100):
    adict = {1:x}
    alist.append(adict)
print(alist)
```

Answer (score 11):

Just put `dict = {}` inside the loop.

```
>>> dict = {}
>>> list = []
>>> for x in range(0, 100):
       dict[1] = x
       list.append(dict)
       dict = {}

>>> print list
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `zip` and list comprehension to do what you need.

If you want the dict values to start at one use `range(1,100)`

```
l = [dict(zip([1],[x])) for x in range(1,100)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `d` is your dictionary. Here, if you do `d.copy()`. It returns shallow copy that doesn't work when you have nested dictionary into `d` dictionary. To overcome from this issue, we have to use **deepcopy**.

```
from copy import deepcopy
list.append(deepcopy(d))
```

It works perfectly !!!