# python list append versus extend for dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have some confusion regarding python's `append` vs. `extend` on a list which is supposed to contain dictionaries:

```
holder = []

element = {}

element["id"] = 1
element["value"] = 2

holder.append(element)

print(holder)
```

prints as expected `[{'id': 1, 'value': 2}]`

however if I use: `holder.extend(element)` instead of `holder.append(element)` the output will be: `['id', 'value']`

Can someone explain me why? ([append vs. extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend) does not apply for this)

Comment: Because iterating dictionary yields keys, not `key-value` pairs. Try `list(element)`

Comment: That question absolutely applies to this - try `holder.extend([{1: 'foo'}, {2: 'bar'}])`. You're just confused about what's being iterated over.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yup, definitely confused ... Now it's a little bit clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.extend()` takes an iterable and appends all elements of the iterable. Dictionary by default iterates over its keys, so all the keys are appended to the list.

`list.append()` takes the object as is and adds it to the list, which is exactly what happend in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Doing `append`, it adds a thing `element`, the dictionary.
Doing `extend`, it adds each thing of `element` if `element` is a list:

```
>>> element = {}
>>> element["id"] = 1
>>> element["value"] = 2
>>> list(element)
['id', 'value']
```

In the case of dictionary, it iterates on the the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Appending a copy of the dictionary to a list seems a better approach especially when creating a list of dictionaries in a loop.

Ref. [Appending a dictionary to a list in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724136/appending-a-dictionary-to-a-list-in-a-loop)

```
holder = []

element = {}

element["id"] = 1
element["value"] = 2
for i in range(10):
    element['value'] = i*2
    holder.append(element.copy())

print(holder)
```